# R regex remove apostroph except the ones preceded and followed by letter

Tags: r, regex

I'm cleaning a text and I'd like to remove any apostrophe except for the ones preceded and followed by letters such as in : i'm, i'll, he's..etc.

I the following preliminary solution, handling many cases, but I want a better one:

```
rmAps <- function(x) gsub("^\'+| \'+|\'+ |[^[:alpha:]]\'+(a-z)*|\\b\'*$", " ", x)

rmAps("'i'm '' ' 'we end' '")
[1] " i'm   we end  "
```

I also tried:

```
(?<![a-z])'(?![a-z])
```

But I think I am still missing sth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gsub("'(?!\\w)|(?<!\\w)'", "", x, perl = TRUE)
#[1] "i'm   we end "
```

Remove occasions when your character is not followed by a word character:  `'(?!\\w)`.

Remove occasions when your character is not preceded by a word character:  `(?<!\\w)'`.

If either of those situations occur, you want to remove it, so `'(?!\\w)|(?<!\\w)'` should do the trick.  Just note that `\\w` includes the underscore, and adjust as necessary.

---

Another option is

```
gsub("\\w'\\w(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|'", "", x, perl = TRUE)
```

In this case, you match any instances when `'` is surrounded by word characters: `\\w'\\w`, and then force that match to fail with `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`.  But, also look for `'` using `|'`.  The result is that only occurrences of `'` not wrapped in word characters will be matched and substituted out.

Comment: why does `gsub('bab\\K|b', '', 'bbabbbbb', perl = TRUE)` not remove the last b but seems to work fine here https://regex101.com/r/bZRoF2/3

Comment: @rawr good question.  Change it up a little to and have a look at what's going on:  `gsub('\\wa\\w\\K|\\w', '', 'bcadefgh', perl = TRUE)`.  It's not the last "b", but the one that comes after 'ab'.  Interesting, `ore`'s version of `gsub` behaves differently:  `ore::ore_subst('\\wa\\w\\K|\\w', '', 'bcadefgh', all = TRUE)`.  It seems like in `\\K` is consuming an extra character in base R, and that I should correct to `gsub('\\wa\\w(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\\w', '', 'bcadefgh', perl = TRUE)` or maybe `gsub('\\wa(?=\\w)\\K|\\w', '', 'bcadefgh', perl = TRUE)`.  I'll need to take a look again later.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regular expression:

```
(?<=\w)'(?=\w)
```

- `(?<=)` is a positive lookbehind. Everything inside needs to match before the next selector
- `(?=)` is a positive lookahead. Everything inside needs to match after the previous selector
- `\w` any alphanumeric character and the underscore

*You could also switch `\w` to e.g. `[a-zA-Z]` if you want to restrict the results.*

**[→ Here is your example on *regex101* for live testing.](https://regex101.com/r/bZRoF2/2)**

Comment: Thanks. But what if I want to negate this, I mean this expression removes what I want to keep.
I tried `(?<!=\w)'(?!=\w)` but it removes all.

Comment: @OmaymaS I've misread the question. In that case you need a negative lookahead/lookbehind. See my updated answer.