# Why does \K appear to consume a character in base R's gsub

Tags: r, regex, pcre

Here is an example string:  `'bcadefgh'`.
I expect that I can match everything except `'cad'` with the following pattern: `'\\wa\\w\\K|\\w'`.
If I want to substitute out everything that isn't `'cad'`, I could use `gsub`, like so `gsub('\\wa\\w\\K|\\w', '', 'bcadefgh', perl = TRUE)`, however this outputs `'cade'`

```
gsub(pattern = '\\wa\\w\\K|\\w', replacement = '', 'bcadefgh', perl = TRUE)
# [1] "cade"
```

My expectation is that \K would cause a reset after the 'd' in 'cad' similar to `'\\wa\\w(*SKIP)(*F)|\\w'`, and so, the following 'e' should be matched and substituted out.  Instead, it appears to me that \K is consuming a character and restarting the match process after 'e'.  Am I misunderstanding this?

With [regex101 (flavor: pcre)](https://regex101.com/r/hdE0nu/1), I get what I expect: everything but 'cad' is matched.

With the `ore` package (Oniguruma regular expressions, not pcre), I get the expected output, as well:

```
ore::ore_subst(regex = '\\wa\\w\\K|\\w',
               replacement = '',
               text = 'bcadefgh',
               all = TRUE)
# [1] "cad"
```

If I go back to `gsub` but use a zero-width positive lookahead for the word character following 'a' instead of consuming it (`(?=\\w)` instead of `\\w`):

```
gsub('\\wa(?=\\w)\\K|\\w', '', 'bcadefgh', perl = TRUE)
# [1] "cad"
```

I get the desired output, but it's not clear to me why this is the case.

What's the explanation for this behavior?

Comment: `(*SKIP)(*F)` approach is the most appropriate when you want to skip some parts of a string when matching, not `\K` that is a kind of a consuming version of a positive lookbehind. Besides, the pattern like yours can be re-written as a mere TRE regex, `gsub('(\\wa\\w)?\\w', '\\1', 'bcadefgh')`, no need for PCRE regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for the input.  It was just an example illustrating my confusion about how \\K was behaving.  The question arose in response to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41915142/r-regex-remove-apostroph-except-the-ones-preceded-and-followed-by-letter) and some comments there rather than needing a solution to this particular example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Advancing After a Zero-Length Regex Match](http://www.regular-expressions.info/zerolength.html):

> The regexp functions in R and PHP are based on PCRE, so they avoid
>   getting stuck on a zero-length match by backtracking like PCRE does.
>   But the `gsub()` function to search-and-replace in R also skips
>   zero-length matches at the position where the previous non-zero-length
>   match ended, like Python does.

Engines differ in sense of encountering zero-length matches. At first glance it seems running a regex like `\s*|\S+` over an input string such as `hello` should return 2 matches:

First match (zero-length match right before `h`):

```
¦h e l l o 
^
```

Second match (whole word):

```
hello 
>>>>>
```

Human thinks this way. From the perspective of a regex engine, it's not true. A well-known engine like PCRE returns three matches (two previous ones and a zero-length match by `\s*` right after last character) but javascript or Python return 6. Because engine skips over next very immediate single character when a zero-length match is found.

```
¦h¦e¦l¦l¦o¦ 
^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
```

So engine satisfies himself with `\s*` part alone. `gsub` works in the same way.