# Reset match token only works every two characters

Tags: r, regex

I would like to add a full stop between each letter of a word using the reset match token (`\K`). I don't want to use a positive lookbehind.

```r
gsub("\\pL\\K", ".", "adskhfks", perl = TRUE)

# [1] "a.ds.kh.fk.s"
```

For some reasons, that only works for every two letters (using RStudio 4.2.0 on macOS 12.31.). It works as expected on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/QiG9T9/1).

Is this normal and is there a fix?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using the lookbehind based pattern in this scenario. PCRE implementation in R is a bit different from PCRE imeplementation for PHP (the one you test at regex101). Surely, you can also capture the letter and then use a backreference in the replacement pattern.

Comment: I think the reason why that happens is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41924971/why-does-k-appear-to-consume-a-character-in-base-rs-gsub

Comment: @Thefourthbird If that explanation was true for all cases, the `(?<=\p{L})` pattern that also matches empty strings would behave in the same way. So, the problem is just with  how `\K` is treated in base R PCRE patterns, not any empty string matching patterns.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The answer there looks like it explain it right? You have `adskhfks` (there is no previously zero-length match), then you match `a` and create the first zero-length match due to the `\K` and and then it does the replacement with `a.` The pattern continues, and now there is a zero length match and skips the next character. That will give `a.ds.kh.fk.s` With the `(?<=\\p{L})` the pattern sees a letter to the left, and replaces it with a dot. The pattern continues, now sees a zero length match and skips to the next position and will create `a.d.s.k.h.f.k.s`

Comment: @Thefourthbird I mean that `.\K` and `(?<=.)` are equivalent patterns both matching empty strings. However, the behavior is different, and `\K` makes the engine advance its index while it is a different story with the lookbehind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug, and instead of your consuming pattern with `\K` operator, you will have to use a lookbehind based pattern:

```r
gsub("(?<=\\p{L})", ".", "adskhfks", perl = TRUE)
```

The `(?<=\p{L})` positive lookbehind matches a location that is immediately preceded with any Unicode letter.

Or, a capturing group with a backreference:

```r
gsub("(\\p{L})", "\\1.", "adskhfks", perl = TRUE)
```

Here, `(\p{L})` captures any Unicode letter into Group 1 and the `\1.` replacement puts back the Group 1 value and appends a dot to it.

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/fPRqSD):

```r
gsub("\\pL\\K", ".", "adskhfks", perl = TRUE)
# [1] "a.ds.kh.fk.s"
gsub("(?<=\\p{L})", ".", "adskhfks", perl = TRUE)
# [1] "a.d.s.k.h.f.k.s."
gsub("(\\pL)", "\\1.", "adskhfks", perl = TRUE)
# [1] "a.d.s.k.h.f.k.s."
```